# How to see only new apps (not updates, or shows apps) in F-Droid "Latest" view?

Tags: f-droid

I'd like to receive or browse new apps in F-Droid's app store.

Currently, it shows both new & updates.

Furthermore, I'd love to filter out apps by category, or by keywords, in F-Droid's "Latest" view or in "Categories".

1. is there a way to acheive it with current tools
2. is there an index I can download and grep / sort / query myself, either programmatically or via script?